# how to fix python fibonacci sequence script?

Tags: python-3.x

My assignment is to create a function that produces 3 lists of the numbers in the fibonacci sequence starting at 0. Here is my code so far.

```
def fibList(n):
    a = 0; b = 1; fibList = []
    if n <= 0:
        return
    elif n == 1:
        fibList = [a]
    elif n == 2:
        fibList = [a,b]
    else:
        for i in range(0,n):
            a, b = b, a + b
            fibList.append(b)

return fibList


def main():
    print (fibList(4))
    print (fibList(10))
    print (fibList(-4))
```

what i want my output to look like is  [0,1,1,2] for 4, [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55] for 10, and [] for -4

My issue begins with fibList(4) currently giving an output of [1, 2, 3, 5] and fibList(10) gives an output of [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89] and for -4 I get "None" instead of a [].
If I type in fibList(1) I get [0] and for fibList(2) I get [0, 1], but when i test fibList(3) the first 0 and 1 are lost, giving me [1,2,3]
How would I go about making it so any number above 3 starts with [0, 1, 1, 2...]? My main issue is getting the 0 and 1 to be the first two numbers in the sequence and getting fibList(-4) to produce a [].
any help or tips would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: The fibanacci sequence is 0,1,1,2,3,5... why are you skipping 2?

Comment: Well, for the `-4` case, your bare `return` is equivalent to `return None`, not `return []`, as you state is your desired outcome. And, in any case above `2`, you are forming the list with only the `b` values appended to an initially empty list (i.e. you're skipping the first two elements)... Also, as @Foon mentioned, your expected output for either positive case seems suspect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that you are missing is to add an empty list in the case of less than or equal to zero, and recurse correctly over your range of Fibonacci numbers greater than 2. Making those small changes like so:

```
def fibList(n):

        if n <= 0:
                fibnums = []
        elif n == 1:
                fibnums = [0]
        elif n >= 2:
                fibnums = [0, 1]
                for i in range(2,n):
                        fibnums.append(fibnums[i-1]+fibnums[i-2])
        return fibnums
```

Note that this recursive method can get quite slow for large numbers, if that is of concern to you with your program. Best of luck!

With these changes,

```
print (fibList(4)) => [0, 1, 1, 2]
print (fibList(10)) => [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
print (fibList(-4)) => []
```

Comment: I made those changes and now I keep getting "invalid syntax"

Comment: @NicholasDePasquale On which line are you getting the invalid syntax? It works fine on my machine running python-3.x.

Answer (score 0):

You did not quite define your function.  Should the resulting list have n values [f(0), ..., f(n-1)] or n+1 values [f(0), ..., f(n)]?  Your examples are contradictory: the 'expected' output for 4 has 4 values ending with f(3) while that for 10 has 11 values ending with f(10).

I am going to assume that the latter is correct.  Here is a revised version of your fast iterative solution.  (If my assumption is wrong, stop the range at n instead of n+1.)

```
def fibs(n):
   "Return [fib(0), ..., fib(n)."
   ret = [0, 1]  # fib(0), fib(1)
   a, b = ret
   if n <= 1:
      return ret[:n+1]
   else:
      for i in range(2, n+1):
         a, b = b, a+b  # b = f(i)
         ret.append(b)
      return ret

print(fibs(-4), fibs(0), fibs(2), fibs(4), fibs(10))

#
[] [0] [0, 1, 1] [0, 1, 1, 2, 3] [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```